# Export data from Google Cloud SQL, and append to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

We have production databases (postgresql and mysql) on Cloud SQL.

How could I export the data from the production databases, and then **append** to BigQuery datasets?

I **DO NOT** want to sync or replicate the data into BigQuery because we purge (after backing up) the production databases on regular basis.

The only method I could think of is:

1. Export to CSV and then drop into Google Cloud Storage
2. Python scrip to append into BigQuery.

Are there any other more optimal ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery supports external data sources, specifically [federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/federated-queries-intro) which allow you to read data directly from a Cloud SQL instance.

You can use this feature to select from all the relevant tables in your Postgres/MySQL instances and copy them into BigQuery without any extra ETL process. You can append the data to your existing tables, create a new table every time, or use some other organization that works for you.

BigQuery also supports [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) so you can automate this.

The actual SQL will depend on your data sources but it's not much more than...

```
INSERT INTO `your_bq_table`
SELECT * 
FROM `external.postgres123.tablename`
```